# Enabling SSI (ServerSide Includes) in JBoss?

Tags: java, jboss, ssi

Any of you guys have enabled SSI (ServerSide Includes) in JBoss? I guess it should be not difficult as it is built on top of a Tomcat instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat already includes in catalina.jar the *org.apache.catalina.ssi.SSIServlet* so just declare the servlet and attach it to a mapping URL, by setting this in the applications *web.xml*

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ssi</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.catalina.ssi.SSIServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>buffered</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>expires</param-name>
        <param-value>60</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>isVirtualWebappRelative</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ssi</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.shtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I put all the parameters, you can see their definition in this [Tomcat SSI](http://www.mbaworld.com/docs/ssi-howto.html) reference.

As the doc says, SSI can bypass security policies so it must be privileged, do this changing the *context.xml* located in *jboss-web.deploy* inside the deploy folder. Just add *privileged="true"* to the root element.

```
<Context ... privileged="true">
```

The servlet will just act as a proxy for the files matching the URL of its mapping.